# consolidate data from multiple sheets excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have 6 sheets of report data that I have run through formulas to standardize the formatting. On these sheets, the data that I need is in Columns `AL:BW`, with varying lengths, and matching headers.

Now, I need to pull all that data together into a summary sheet to more easily create charts/reports.  I am pretty sure that VBA will be able to solve, but I haven't found an answer online that will allow me to select the same range of columns on each sheet and compile that data in a summary sheet.

I have been experimenting with the solution from this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793964(v=office.12).aspx) but I don't know enough about VBA to specifically target the data in the `AL:BW` columns.

```
Sub CopyData()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim shLast As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range
    Dim StartRow As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    ' Delete the summary sheet if it exists.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CombinedData").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' Add a new summary worksheet.
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "CombinedData"

    ' Fill in the start row.
    StartRow = 2

    ' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
    ' summary worksheet.
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If LCase(Left(sh.Name, 4)) = "?-??" Then


            ' If source worksheet is not empty and if the last
            ' row >= StartRow, copy the range.
            If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then
                'Set the range that you want to copy
                Set CopyRng = sh.Range("AL:BL")

               ' Test to see whether there are enough rows in the summary
               ' worksheet to copy all the data.
                If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                   MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
                   "summary worksheet to place the data."
                   GoTo ExitTheSub
                End If

                ' This statement copies values and formats.
                CopyRng.Copy
                With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End With


End Sub
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.  Just change the copy range.

```
'Fill in the range that you want to copy
'Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:G1")

Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "RDBMergeSheet" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "RDBMergeSheet"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

            'Find the last row with data on the DestSh
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)

            'Fill in the range that you want to copy
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:G1")

            'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
            'values or want to copy everything look at the example below this macro
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

            'Optional: This will copy the sheet name in the H column
            DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "H").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist.  For some reason, the macro isn't actually consolidating data.  I made a few tweaks, but haven't been able to pinpoint the problem. Thanks for trying though

Comment: I forgot to include the functions the get the last row and last column.  I just added them.  try it again and give me feedback.

Comment: It works!  I have a few extra sheets in my workbook that I would like to exclude from the Macro.  Is there a way to target only worksheets that are formatted "?-??" where "?" "is a variable?

Comment: What do you mean formatted?  What's that?  You can exclude sheets. based on the name of the sheets:  If wks.Name <> "Name1" And wks.Name <> "Name2" And wks.Name <> "Name3" . . . do stuff . .  .End If